# Benefits of employing devices that support vlan trunking

Tags: vlan

What are the benefits of employing devices that support vlan trunking. Would this feature be a useful addition for a **symmetric switch that has no support ether channel?**

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

VLAN trunking is useful and necessary for building a VLAN-partitioned network encompassing multiple switches. VLAN trunks allow you to connect a large number of VLANs across a single link (or aggregation group).

Without trunking and appropriate tagging you'd need to run a dedicated, physical link for each VLAN connection between switches (port-based VLAN).

Whether or not the switches support link aggregation (static LAG, LACP, EtherChannel) doesn't matter but pretty much all VLAN-capable switches do. Note that you can only use *unmanaged* switches (generally incapable of VLAN trunking and link aggregation) with a single, untagged VLAN each.

Answer (score 6):

VLAN (trunking) and EtherChannel are totally unrelated.

- VLANs allow the separation of a physical switch into several logical switches. 
  Note that any device that supports VLANs also support VLAN trunking.
- LinkAggregation (the standardized version of Cisco Etherchannel technology) permits to have several physical links acting as a single one, providing fault tolerance and higher bandwidth.

Now since those technologies are pretty standard, most of devices that support one of them also support the other.

Back to first question:

> What are the benefits of employing devices that support vlan trunking.

If you use VLANs on a switch and want to extend those VLANs across several switches (for example you how no more ports available on the switch) then you need to transport several VLANs on a link between the two switches. This is what VLAN trunking is made for. Without trunking, you would need a dedicated physical link between the switches for each VLAN, which doesn't scale well.

Comment: Note that you *could* extend multiple VLANs among several switches by using separate non-trunked ports for each VLAN between the switches, so the primary benefit to VLAN trunking (from my point of view, at least) from the switch perspective is maximizing the use of a small number of ports. That extends to devices that only have one port available for a connection (e.g., a firewall) where it's the *only* way to connect multiple VLANs to a device.

Comment: @ToddWilcox thanks for the comment, I have amended the answer.